# ASP.Net Selected Item in dynamic drop-down

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make the selected item the value of an `asp:Label` if this is possible

I am putting my drop down list in like this

```
For ddlAdults As Integer = 1 To strNumberSlept
CType(e.Item.FindControl("ddlEditAdults"), dropdownlist).Items.Add(new ListItem(ddlAdults.ToString(), ddlAdults.ToString()))
Next ddlAdults
```

And I need to add a selected item in to be the value of `strSelectedItem`

```
Dim strSelectedItem = CType(e.Item.FindControl("lblAdults"), label).Text
```

Not sure how to add this in dynamically

Any ideas?

Thanks

Jamie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out

```
CType(e.Item.FindControl("ddlEditAdults"), dropdownlist).SelectedValue = CType(e.Item.FindControl("lblAdults"), label).Text
```

Thanks

Jamie